# what's the difference between ElasticSearch http ports in different nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

We know each ES node has 9200(default) http port for CRUD operation. And there are three types ES nodes: Master, Data and Client. 
So my question is that the same http port in different node type acting different roles or say they are little bit different? 
I have the question just because I saw different result when I query the http port in different node type sometimes.

It seems something very weird when I call Master's http port.Did you guys meet this situation please? Is that because some cache data? Thanks!

Comment: There's no difference between HTTP ports for any node type. Can you explain how your cluster is configured and show some of those weird example queries/results you encountered?

Comment: I just upgraded from ES1.5 to ES2.1. After I deleted an index, I recreated it again. When I called Master http port it said the index already exists, but I did delete it(tried many times and response ok). While when I changed to call client node http port to recreate the index, it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: It's a Cluster configuration issue, I'm gonna close the question, thanks a lot Val!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!